# Spring cloud function with as http end point with path variable

Tags: spring-cloud-function

I want to use Spring cloud function so I started it with as http end point. It works great but how do I use it with path variable. Say I want to make an end point like this: http://localhost:8080/myFunction/{id}?

How to accomplish it via Spring cloud function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure where did you get `org.springframework.cloud.function.web.FunctionRequest`. It does not exist.
Also, why do you need `MyFunctionController`? I am struggling to understand what you are trying to accomplish. `MyFunction` is all you need to access `http://localhost:8080/myFunction/123`

Comment: so 123 is injected as @Pathvariable in spring MVC?

Comment: What Spring MVC? The question is about Spring Cloud Function which is not Spring MVC

Comment: Yes of course I just trying to make comparison between Spring cloud function and Spring MVC to better understand how Spring cloud function works as http end point

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official Spring Cloud Function documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-function/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-function.html#_http_request_parameters), HTTP request parameters can be handled as follows:

> As you have noticed from the previous table, you can pass an argument to a function as path variable (i.e., `/{function}/{item}`). For example, http://localhost:8080/uppercase/foo will result in calling `uppercase` function with its input parameter being `foo`.
>
> While this is the recommended approach and the one that fits most use cases cases, there are times when you have to deal with HTTP request parameters (e.g., http://localhost:8080/uppercase/foo?name=Bill) The framework will treat HTTP request parameters similar to the HTTP headers by storing them in the `Message` headers under the header key `http_request_param` with its value being a `Map` of request parameters, so in order to access them your function input signature should accept `Message` type (e.g., `Function<Message<String>, String>`). For convenience we provide `HeaderUtils.HTTP_REQUEST_PARAM` constant.

Answer (score -1):

1. Assuming you are using Spring with Maven and a pom.xml specified you can include the dependency for Spring Cloud Function and Spring Web:

   ```
   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-web</artifactId>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   ```

---

2. Then try creating or altering your bean. This would create a simple Function that takes a String input (the path variable id) and returns a String response:

   ```
   import java.util.function.Function;
   import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

   @Component
   public class MyFunction implements Function<String, String> {
       @Override
       public String apply(String id) {
           // Your function logic here
           return "Received ID: " + id;
       }
   }
   ```

---

3. Next try creating or altering your controller to expose this function as an HTTP endpoint with a path variable. You can use the @RestController and @RequestMapping annotations for this. Below we injected the FunctionRequest for your MyFunction bean and create a GET mapping that accepts a path variable {id}. When a request is made to http://localhost:8080/myFunction/{id}, the handleRequest method is called, and it invokes your function with the provided id:

   ```
   import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
   import org.springframework.cloud.function.web.FunctionRequest;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

   @RestController
   @RequestMapping("/myFunction")
   public class MyFunctionController {
       @Autowired
       private FunctionRequest<MyFunction> functionRequest;

       @GetMapping("/{id}")
       public String handleRequest(@PathVariable String id) {
           return functionRequest.apply(id);
       }
   }
   ```

---

4. Finally try running your Spring Boot application, and you can access your function using the endpoint, `http://localhost:8080/myFunction/123`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: FunctionRequest is not recognize...I use Spring boot 3.1